# Web Crawler in Python

Tags: python, parsing, web-crawler

I'm trying to write a basic web crawler in Python. The trouble I have is parsing the page to extract url's. I've both tried BeautifulSoup and regex however I cannot achieve an efficient solution.

As an example: I'm trying to extract all the member urls in Facebook's Github page. (https://github.com/facebook?tab=members). The code I've written extracts member URL's;

```
def getMembers(url):
  text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read();
  soup = BeautifulSoup(text);
  memberList = []
    #Retrieve every user from the company
    #url = "https://github.com/facebook?tab=members"

  data = soup.findAll('ul',attrs={'class':'members-list'});
  for div in data:
    links = div.findAll('li')
    for link in links:
          memberList.append("https://github.com" + str(link.a['href']))

  return memberList
```

However this takes quite a while to parse and I was wondering if I could do it more efficiently, since crawling process is too long.

Comment: Have you tried using a different parser?  You can use the [lxml](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) parser with beautiful soup, making it quite quick.

Comment: @kreativitea I'm checking it right now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Sure, this not your internet connection? Processing itself should be quick. My suggestions: write your output to a file, and check how long it takes.

Comment: measure separately how long it takes to get text (urllib2) and to find links in it (BeautifulSoup). You could use timeit.default_timer() or run `python -mcProfile your_script.py` github might be responding sloowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use GitHub API, that let you do exactly what you want to accomplish. Then it's only a matter of using a json parser and you are done.

http://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/members/

Answer (score 1):

In order to prevent writing the scraper yourself you can use available ones. Maybe try scrapy, it uses python and it's available on github. 
http://scrapy.org/

Answer (score 0):

Check the post [Extremely Simple Web Crawler](http://remotalks.blogspot.com/2014/05/an-extremely-simple-and-effective-web.html) for a simple and easy to understand python script that crawls webpages and collects all the valid hyperlinks depending on the seed URL and depth: